# Can AR models be written as MA models?

Tags: time-series

I heard that $AR(1)$ can be written as $MA(\infty)$.

Can $AR(p), p \in \mathbb N, p \ge 2$ be written as $MA(q)$ for some $q$?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

An AR can be inverted to produce an infinite MA.

Take an autoregressive model of order $p$, which [by definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive_model#Definition) is of the form:

$X_{t}=\mu_0+\phi_1X_{t-1}+\phi_2X_{t-2}+\ldots+\phi_pX_{t-p}+\varepsilon _{t}\,$

$\quad\,\,=\mu_0+\phi_1B^1X_{t}+\phi_2B^2X_{t}+\ldots+\phi_pB^pX_{t}+\varepsilon _{t}\,$, where $B$ is the [backshift operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lag_operator#Lag_polynomials), so

$X_{t}-\phi_1B^1X_{t}-\phi_2B^2X_{t}-\ldots-\phi_pB^pX_{t}=\mu_0+\varepsilon _{t}\,$, or

$\phi(B) X_t = \mu_0 + \varepsilon_t$, where $\phi_p(B) = 1 - \phi_1 B - \phi_2 B^2 - \cdots - \phi_p B^p$.

Then $X_t = \phi(B)^{-1}\mu_0 +  \phi(B)^{-1} \varepsilon_t$, which is an infinite MA.

Comment: Can you explain the formulation of AR a little better here? My understanding is that an AR(1) model was just a linear model having a conditional covariance for the outcome structured as the following: $\Sigma_{ i, j } = \rho^{|i-j|}; \rho \in (0, 1)$.

Comment: Well, yes that's true for an AR(1), but it's a consequence of the definition of an AR, which writes the model (conditionally) as a regression. I've added a little more detail at the start of my answer, but if it isn't sufficient, please let me know.

Comment: Thanks! Can you write $ϕ(B)^{-1} \mu_0 + ϕ(B)^{-1}ε_t$ as the more common form of a MA model, i.e. $a+ \sum_i \theta_{i=1}^\infty \epsilon_{t-i}$? Is there some condition needed to write it that way? Can $ϕ(B)^{-1} \mu_0 + ϕ(B)^{-1}ε_t$ be thought as a MA model? If

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series#Inverting_series